# Better way to write this MySQL query (JOIN)

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE field1=(SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE type=1) 
OR field2=(SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE type=1)
```

What's the proper way to write this query? It currently doesn't work because the subqueries return more than one row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE field1 IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE type=1) 
OR field2 IN(SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE type=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `IN`:

```
delete
from table1
where field1 in (
        select id
        from table2
        where type = 1
        )
    or field2 in (
        select id
        from table2
        where type = 1
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your tables, you might be able to get away with the IN-approach. if they're on the larger side, you can go for the DELETE...USING syntax.

```
DELETE FROM foo USING foo, bar WHERE foo.field1=bar.id OR foo.field2=bar.id
```